# Retrieved Audio Capture Device Names Differ When Queried in JavaFX Thread vs 'Plain' Java Thread

Tags: javafx, audio, device, capture

I've come across an odd behaviour when querying the names of audio capture devices in a JavaFX thread vs a 'plain' Java thread.

Normally I probably would not have noticed, except that I have some non-JavaFX applications which share a common configuration pool with a JavaFX application, and this caused some issues when programmatically setting a capture audio device to use.

In a nutshell, the same query main in a plain Java thread returns capture device names truncated to 31 characters, whereas in a JavaFX thread the capture device names are 'full'.

For example, truncated results...

```
Primary Sound Capture Driver
Microphone (HD Pro Webcam C910)
Microphone (Realtek(R) Audio)
Headset (Bose QuietComfort 35 H
Headset Microphone (Oculus Virt
```

...vs 'full' results:

```
Primary Sound Capture Driver
Microphone (HD Pro Webcam C910)
Microphone (Realtek(R) Audio)
Headset (Bose QuietComfort 35 Hands-Free)
Headset Microphone (Oculus Virtual Audio Device)
```

The minimal JavaFX application code below demonstrates the issue, and in my testing it happens in both 32 bit and 64 bit versions of the Java8 JDK on Windows 10. I have not tested non-Windows platforms, so I am not sure if the behaviour occurs outside this environment.

The `showCaptureDeviceNames()` method does the query and printout of the device names. If called from the `main` method, truncated devices names are shown. If commented out of `main` and triggered by the button press in the JavaFX thread, 'full' device names are shown.

Interestingly, if called in `main` *first*, and later in the JavaFX thread, truncated names are shown, indicating that there is some sort of caching going on (which luckily provides a workaround for my problem). Simply calling `AudioSystem.getMixerInfo();` all by itself is sufficient to induce the 'caching' effect

Also, this only happens for *capture* devices; if the `TargetDataLine.class` is switched to `SourceDataLine.class` to filter for *playback* devices, the device name is always 'full'.

Can anyone offer any hints as to why this might be happening?

My current workaround is to ensure that the JavaFX application queries all audio devices *before* the JavaFX thread kicks off by calling `AudioSystem.getMixerInfo();` in `main(...)`. This works, but... as a "fix" it looks more like a mistake sitting there on its own for no apparent reason (although adequate commenting will help future developers who come across it).

I'd love for someone to tell me I'm doing something wrong and there's a better way.

```
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Line;
import javax.sound.sampled.Mixer;
import javax.sound.sampled.Mixer.Info;
import javax.sound.sampled.TargetDataLine;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class CaptureDeviceListTest extends Application
{
    @Override
    public void start( Stage primaryStage )
        throws Exception
    {
        primaryStage.setTitle( "Test Capture Device Queries" );

        Button btn = new Button( "Get capture device names" );
        btn.setOnAction( event -> showCaptureDeviceNames() );

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add( btn );
        primaryStage.setScene( new Scene( root, 200, 200 ) );
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private static void showCaptureDeviceNames()
    {
        // filter for capture devices - change to `SourceTargetData.class` for playback devices
        Line.Info captureLine = new Line.Info( TargetDataLine.class );
        for( Info mixerInfo : AudioSystem.getMixerInfo() )
        {
            Mixer mixer = AudioSystem.getMixer( mixerInfo );
            if( mixer.isLineSupported( captureLine ) )
                System.out.println( mixerInfo.getName() );
        }
    }

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        // COMMENT / UNCOMMENT THE NEXT LINE
        // showCaptureDeviceNames();
        launch( args );
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce the problem with Java 14 and JavaFX 14.0.1.

Comment: I don't think it is just JavaFX thread, I did some tests and I stopped at some native calls. You can check these issues: [Name from Mixer.Info's getName() method is truncated string of ~30 chars](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8079603), [Mixer names (capture and ports) are truncated to 31 symbols (Windows)](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-7116070), [Java sound API MixerInfo: multi-byte characters are garbled](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8071714)

Comment: I think it has something to do with initialization. If you call `AudioSystem.getMixerInfo()` from the `JavaFX` thread the first time, then if you call it from another thread, you'll get the correct results.

Comment: @slaw, thanks for checking and that extra detail - would you be able to confirm whether Java/JavaFX 14 both produce the truncated or 'full' device names? I assume that you mean the latter, but it would be good to have confirmation on that.

Comment: @M.S. Those two issues you link to seem to describe the behaviour exactly - thanks for the references. WIth regard to the initialisation order, that's kind of what my example code was supposed to demonstrate; apologies if it wasn't clear in my explanation.

Basically if it's called in `main` first you get the truncated names, if it's called in the JavaFX thread first, you get the 'full' names. This means the device names are inconsistent, but predictable, and least gives me a workaround for the problem I have communicating with a separate "plain Java" application.

Comment: I assume I'm seeing the full names. At least, none of my (apparently two) devices had clearly truncated names like your example. But I also don't think the names of either of my devices were as long as the ones that are truncated in your example (i.e. your last two devices).